# Producer consumer problem display a wrong order

Tags: java, oop, producer-consumer

Following producer consumer code displays a wrong order(before producer produce consumer consumes. sometimes producer produce many items(cubbyhole allows one item only)). why is that?

```
  public class CubbyHole {
    private int content;
    private boolean available=false;

   public synchronized int get() {
      while (available == false) {
         try {
            wait();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      }
      available = false;
      notify();
      return content;
   }
   public synchronized void put(int value) {
      while (available == true) {
         try {            
            wait();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) { } 
      }
      content = value;
      available = true;
      notifyAll();
      }
   } 

public class Consumer extends Thread {
    CubbyHole c;

    public Consumer(CubbyHole c){
        this.c=c;
    }

    public void run(){
        int val=0;
        for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
            val=c.get();
            System.out.println("consumer gets "+val);
        }
    }

}

public class Producer extends Thread {
    CubbyHole c;

    public Producer(CubbyHole c){
        this.c=c;
    }
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            c.put(i);
            System.out.println("Producer puts "+i);
        }

    }

}
public class Dimo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CubbyHole c = new CubbyHole();
        Producer p = new Producer(c);
        Consumer con = new Consumer(c);
        p.start();
        con.start();

    }
}
```

this code gets the following output

```
Producer puts 0
Producer puts 1
consumer gets 0
consumer gets 1
Producer puts 2
Producer puts 3
consumer gets 2
consumer gets 3
Producer puts 4
consumer gets 4
consumer gets 5
Producer puts 5
Producer puts 6
consumer gets 6
Producer puts 7
Producer puts 8
consumer gets 7
consumer gets 8
Producer puts 9
consumer gets 9
```

can anyone explain what is wrong with this code? how to get the correct order in this code?

Comment: Define correct order. Looks fine to me - you're printing outside the lock.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's already enforced by the use of a `boolean` semaphore. The issue is with the data race in printing.

Comment: @BoristheSpider the Spider this is the order which i want                                        Producer puts 0
consumer gets 0
Producer puts 1
consumer gets 1
Producer puts 2
consumer gets 2
Producer puts 3
consumer gets 3
.... etc

Comment: You will need to print inside the lock to prevent interleaving.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you very much. it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these two lines:

```
val=c.get();
System.out.println("consumer gets "+val);
```

What can happen is the consumer calls the cubby hole and waits there while it is free. It then gets the value and releases it. Now between these two lines - after c.get() and before the printlin the other thread can finish its whole process - call put(i) and print. That's when you will get two producer.put() values.

You should move the printing part inside the cubby hole code to make sure it prints what you want.